# Induction in finite groups

Tags: proof-writing, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose I want to prove some property $P$ for $G$. Suppose that the property $P$ holds for all groups less than $|G|$. If I have a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $|H| < |G|$ then $H$ has property $P$. If I find another subgroup of $G$, say $K$, satisfying property $P$ and $|H| < |K|$. Can it be concluded by induction that $G$ has property $P$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $P$ be the property "$G$ is abelian." Let $G$ be the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ -- this group is not abelian. Every proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian, because $G$ has $6$ elements and every group with less than $6$ elements is abelian.